# Insert multiple rows from two tables into one table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, merge

I have two tables with a number of rows in each. I want to "merge" these two into another table, how would I go about and do that?

I've tried `INSERT INTO SELECT`, but it's not doing what I want (or maybe I'm possibly doing it wrong).

The Tables I have are:

```
Versions
  [version] VARCHAR(10)

Semesters
  [id] INT
  [semester] INT
  [name] VARCHAR(150)

Versions_semesters
  [semesterid] INT
  [version] VARCHAR(10)
```

Some example data from Versions and Semesters:

```
Versions
  'Version1.0'
  'Version1.5'

Semesters
  1, 15, 'Autumn15'
  2, 15, 'Spring15'
  3, 15, 'Fall15'
  4, 16, 'Autumn16'
  5, 16, 'Spring16'
  6, 16, 'Fall16'
```

What I'd want to achieve is a table holding versions related to semesterIDs.

I can get the subsets I want by doing the following:

```
SELECT id FROM semesters WHERE semester = 16;
SELECT * from Versions;
```

And these two subsets I'd like to `INSERT INTO Versions_semesters` so it looks like this:

```
Versions_semesters
  4, 'Version1.0'
  5, 'Version1.0'
  6, 'Version1.0'
  4, 'Version1.5'
  5, 'Version1.5'
  6, 'Version1.5'
```

Anyone have an elegant (or ugly) solution to this? I guess a `CROSS JOIN` could be used as I have the subsets extracted, but how do I do both get the subsets and then Join them?

Comment: Is there a link between these tables or do you want to insert every possible combinations?

Comment: The relationship is that the tables are much larger, and I'd like to assign some of the IDs to multiple versions. In natural language I'd like the table to say for example: "ID 1 is connected with version 1, 1.5, 2 and 3".

Comment: Ok now i see, there was no example when i posted my comment, your goal is to have every possible combinations (`CROSS JOIN`)

Comment: Do you have a specific `logic` behind this? or is it random?

Comment: There is no coded-logic as of now. The only logic is that I have a specific set of versions but a huge amount of IDs, and all versions don't apply to all IDs.

Comment: If you wanted coded then there must be a logic to code. If there is non, then you are alone choosing manually what should go and what not.

Comment: Why does version 1.5 get a record for ID 1 and 2 but not ID 3? Similarly why does ID 3 match with Version 2.0 when no other records do? How are we supposed to know which versions apply to which IDs if you don't tell us. Unfortunately *"all versions don't apply to all IDs"* is far to vague to be helpful.

Comment: I'll revise my question. Sorry for being unprecise. I tried keeping the text down but I guess I shot myself in the foot in the process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for a `CROSS JOIN` which is the Cartesian product of the two tables.

```
INSERT INTO Table3
(ID,Version)
SELECT Id,Version
FROM Table1 CROSS JOIN Table2
```

Comment: Thank you! This led me to the following solution:

1: Declare a temporary table holding the subset of semesterids I want.

2: Cross Join the semesterids with versions.

3: Insert the cross join into versions_semesters

Also thanks to @Joël Salamin for the reply you removed!